# How do I get matplotlib.pyplot to label every few labels down the Y-Axis?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, matplotlib, graph

I'm attempting to plot data from a .csv file and I want it to put less values down the Y-axis.

This is the output I am getting at the moment:
[image: This]

I would also like the numbers to be automatically rounded or neatened up to make the plot more readable.

```
def GraphBuilder():
    item = 0
    savenumber = 1
    ColumnTime = itemgetter(0)(column_names)
    while item < col_count:
        SecondaryColumn = itemgetter(item)(column_names)
        ColumnTimeData = pandagraph[ColumnTime]
        SecondaryColumnData = pandagraph[(SecondaryColumn)]
        plt.xlim([0, 1000])
        plt.ylim([-100, 100000])
        plt.ylabel(SecondaryColumn)
        plt.plot(ColumnTimeData, SecondaryColumnData)
        plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
        print("Starting new graph")
        Start = 0
        End = 0
        Start = time.time()
        plt.savefig(f"Graph{savenumber}.tiff")
        plt.close()
        plt.cla()
        plt.clf()
        print(f"Graph {savenumber} completed")
        End = time.time()
        TotalGraphTime = End - Start
        TotalGraphTime = round(TotalGraphTime, 2)
        print("Graph completed in: ", TotalGraphTime, " Seconds.")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        item += 1
        savenumber +=1
```

I'm not sure how to make the program do this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the datatype of the values in `SecondaryColumnData`?

Comment: Should be float

Comment: You probably want to use a [`MaxNLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator)

Answer (score -1):

To change the number of ticks I would suggest checking out plt.yticks